# Is the category of sets fully embedded in the category of preorders?

Tags: category-theory

Let SET be a category of sets, and POS be a category of preorders with order-preserving mappings.

I met the following problem in my course on Category Theory:

> Construct a full embedding of the SET into the POS.

The first idea that came to my mind was the following:

- we send each set $X$ to $\left( \mathcal{P} \left( X \right), \subseteq \right)$;
- if $f$ is the function from $X$ to $Y$, then $f'$ is the function from $\left( \mathcal{P} \left( X \right), \subseteq \right)$ to $\left( \mathcal{P} \left( Y \right), \subseteq \right)$ such that $f' \left( Z \right) = f \left[Z \right]$ for all $Z \subseteq X$.

Such functor is embedding, but isn't full embedding. And then I have stuck.

Any hints?

Comment: It's much easier than that, you can take the trivial preorder $x \le x$.

Comment: I think it would also work to take the full preorder where $x \le y$ for every $x,y$, i.e. $X \mapsto (X, X \times X)$.  (Whereas the suggestion by Qiaochu Yuan I think is $X \mapsto (X, \Delta_X)$ where $\Delta_X = \{ (x, y) \in X \times X \mid x = y \}$ is the diagonal.)

Comment: Yes, it really was a lot easier than I thought... Now I'm ashamed.

Thank you very much!